# Electric shock through thick rubber tube filled with coolant and carrying a high voltage wire

Tags: high-voltage, high-frequency, cooling, insulation

I have two Litz wires coming out of a coil. The coil is driven with short pulses of 20 kHz sinosoidal voltage with a peak of 1.4kV. Each Litz wire is insulated by 3 thin layers of mylar sheets in addition to the individual strand insulation. Each wire is individually threaded through a thick (3mm wall) EPDM rubber tube that carries coolant fluid (link below) to the coil. When I touch the outside of either of the two rubber tubes leading to the coil I get a little electric shock. I get how this could happen if I touch the thin insulation of the Litz wire directly, but how does it happen also through the thick rubber? The coolant is somewhat conductive. I'm guessing it might have to do with that, but I don't exactly understand how or why?

EPDM tube: https://shop.watercool.de/HEATKILLER-EPDM-Tubing-16-10-ID3-8-schwarz-3m-Retailbox_1

Coolant: https://www.webshop-innovatek.de/en/coolant-additives/all-coolants/63/innovatek-protect-ip-application-mix-25

Comment: The capacitive coupling though the 3 mm insulation at 20 kHz will be significant! EDPM is fairly conductive. Can you ground the rubber part?

Comment: You are right, I've just measured the resistance of a tube section and got a value in the 10s of kOhm range at 20 kHz. I haven't considered that at all! I will definitely use a different material for the tube, or seperate the tube and wire and add extra insulation on the Litz wire. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Remember that if this is in continous use, you may need to have sacrificial electrodes in your coolant which controls your grounding. I can't say for sure 1.4 kV is high enough to warrant it, but you are approacing one of many phenomonons which comes with high voltage and water cooling.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the tip! In the actual application I was thinking of using either distilled water to minimize conductivity, or transformer oil for the insulating properties. Do you think either of these options would help with these issues?

Comment: Distilled water at high voltage is a PhD subject of its own. Unless you have continuous ion exchange filters, it won’t stay distilled, that’s for sure. Transformer oil is Gods gift to EEs around the world until you have a fire.

Comment: That's good to know! Thanks again for the helpful answers!